# Bijection between filters and ideals

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, filters

Let {$F_\alpha$}$_{\alpha \in I}$ - fields.
=> $\exists$ bijections between filters over $D$, where $D$ is filter and ideals of $\prod F_\alpha$.
In this case ultrafilter corresponds to max ideals.

I tried to use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242231/ring-and-filters) question, but I didn't reach any useful conclusions.

Comment: 'Filters over $D$ where $D$ is filter' Are you sure that's correct?

Comment: @Mathematician42 this is formulation from my lecturer, but it embarrasses me too

Answer (score 2):

Let $U$ be a filter over $I$. Consider the assignment $$U\mapsto \left\{a\in \prod_{i\in I}F_i\mid \left\{i\in I\mid a(i)=0\right\}\in U\right\}.$$

I claim this gives a bijection between filters over $I$ and ideals of $\prod_{i\in I}F_i$. First of all we claim that $\left\{a\in \prod_{i\in I}F_i\mid \left\{i\in I\mid a(i)=0\right\}\in U\right\}$ is an ideal of $\prod_{i\in I}F_i$. So let $b\in \prod_{i\in I}F_i$. Then $(ba)(i)=b(i)a(i)=0$. It follows that $\left\{i\in I\mid (ba)(i)=0\right\}\subset \left\{i\in I\mid a(i)=0\right\}$. By definition of a filter, we have that $\left\{i\in I\mid (ba)(i)=0\right\}\in U$. Hence $\left\{a\in \prod_{i\in I}F_i\mid \left\{i\in I\mid a(i)=0\right\}\in U\right\}$ really is an ideal.

It remains to show that the assignment is a bijection. (Try this, also, you can only filter something w.r.t. an ordered set, do you see which ordered set I'm using?)