# Filter/Ultrafilter Methods in Commutative Algebra/ ring theory

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, model-theory, filters

I have a rather broad question: Are there any useful results/ approaches known  on study commutative unitary rings and their ideals with *filter/ ultrafilter* methods?

What I know:

1. In Boolean algebra ideals are dual objects to filters (that's of course a very special ring)
2. If $R$  is the direct product of a family of fields $F_{\alpha}$ indexed by a set $X$, ie $R= \prod_{\alpha \in X} F_{\alpha}$, then there exist a very strong relation: the proper ideals in $R$ are in bijective correpondence with the filters $F$ on $X$, see [this discussion.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242231/ring-and-filters?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Is this the only interesting connection using filters as abstract toolbox to analyse structure of rings and their ideals or are there more?

More generally are there any general heuristics known when one may expect that the application of filter methods to some mathematical subarea could provide interesting results, and on the other hand when one should expect it's nearly useless (as seemingly here in the case for rings which are not fields). Can this 'dissonance' be explaned in heuristic terms?

My problem is that I have rather bad intuition for filters (...at latest when nonprincipal ultrafilters come into the game, my intuition tends instantly to say goodbye) and I'm wondering
if it's possible to develop some kind of intuition when filter methods might provide some new insight at the studied topic, and when tendentilly not. For study of rings it seems that filter methods not provide something new. Is there a heuristic reason why at least in this case for rings & ideals applying filter methods tends (...except for the case of products of fields) not to unravel some new interesting insights about the structure?

Hope, that the question is too vaguely formulated, it's primarily about intuition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a series of papers that tries to generalize the description of prime ideals in a product of fields that you mentioned in your question to products of more general rings. A reference for results of this type and for further literature might be [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.03069).

A short summary:

Let $\Lambda$ be a set and $(D_\lambda)_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ a family of commutative rings.

1. The maximal ideals of the product $\prod_{\lambda} D_\lambda$ are all induced by ultrafilters on the disjoint union of the $\text{Max-Spec}(D_\lambda)$, the sets of maximal ideals of the $D_\lambda$.
2. If the $D_\lambda$ are domains then the minimal prime ideals of the product are in bijective correspondence with ultrafilters on the index set, just as for fields.
3. If all $D_\lambda$ are Prüfer domains (see the definition below), one can describe all prime ideals of the product in terms of the ultrafilters of point 1.

---

Another phenomenon, where ultrafilters can be used in a very practical way, is the [constructible topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_topology). It is the unique compact Hausdorff topology on the spectrum of a commutative ring that refines the Zariski topology. Originally, it had been described by the open compact sets as a basis of clopen sets. However, this is not very practical for everyday use.

But the closure operation can be described very intuitively by ultrafilters (see the paper by [Fontana and Loper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/1773576_The_Patch_Topology_and_the_Ultrafilter_Topology_on_the_Prime_Spectrum_of_a_Commutative_Ring) and, for a very clever and short proof, the one by [Finocchiaro](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/256846460_Spectral_Spaces_and_Ultrafilters)) in the following way:

Let $A$ be a commutative ring and $Y$ be a subset of $\text{Spec}(A)$. For an ultrafilter $\mathcal U$ on $Y$, one defines $Y_{\mathcal U} = \{ a \in A \mid V(a) \cap Y \in \mathcal U \}$. This set forms a prime ideal of $A$ and is called the *ultrafilter limit point* of $Y$ with respect to $A$.

The closure of $Y$ in the constructible topology is the set of all ultrafilter limit points of $Y$.

---

An integral domain $D$ is called a *Prüfer domain* if it satisfies one of the following equivalent conditions (see also the monograph on multiplicative ideal theory by Robert Gilmer):

- Every non-zero finitely generated ideal is invertible.
- The localization $D_M$ is a valuation domain for each maximal ideal $M$ of $D$.
- The set of ideals of $D$ with $+$ and $\cap$ is a distributive lattice.

Indeed, there are many more equivalent conditions.
The Noetherian Prüfer domains are exactly the Dedekind domains.

Comment: two aspects to clarify: 1. When you say in point 1. that the maximal ideals of the product are all induced by ultrafilters, then you mean that these are the the "points of convergence" of the principal ultrafilters, right? 2. In definition of Prüfer domain, first point, by an "invertible ideal" you mean that in the sense of commutative algebra, that locally it is generated by one regular element, ie like the ideal sheaf of a Cartier divisor?

Comment: 1. What you say is true for the maximal ideals that come from the component rings. But in general there are many more maximal ideals in the product. These come from non-principal ultrafilters on this disjoint union in a more complicated way.
2. Yes, that's exactly what it means, finitely generated and locally free of rank one.

Comment: I added one more topic to the answer.

Comment: I see, so that's essentially the maximal ideals which cannot be constructed explicitely, so in that sense perfectly "mirror the spirit" of non-principal ultrafilters in certain sense?

Comment: On the "Let $A$ be a commutative ring and $Y$ subset of $\text{Spec}(A)$..."-part: are in that sense the ultrafilters "height-sensitive", in the sense that they not only capture information on maximal ideals as "set", but of all primes and moreover their [height](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Height_of_an_ideal)?

Comment: That's interesting: so as far I understand it the upshot is that the ultrafilters 
capture exactly (as one might expect) the topological picture 
of $\text{Spec}(A)$ (indeed the prime ideals are detected 
by topology), but miss the pure algebraic nuances (e.g. nilpotence 
phenomena in the sense eg that the ultrafilters "not see" the difference between 
information provided eg by $A$ and $A/Rad(A)$), right?

Comment: You are right, the ultrafilters on the given subset $Y\subseteq \text{Spec}(A)$ capture information on the height of the ultrafilter limit points.

Comment: Well, yes, a topology is of course uniquely determined by its closure operation and in that sense the ultrafilters capture the topological information on the spectrum with the constructible topology. 

Of course, they do not see all algebraic information on the element level of the ring because, as you showed with your example, not even the prime ideals themselve do.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't read the following book, but it might be interesting to you.

Hans Schoutens
The Use of Ultraproducts in Commutative Algebra
Lecture Notes in Mathematics, volume 1999, 2010.

Here is the publisher's description of the book:

*In spite of some recent applications of ultraproducts in algebra, they remain largely unknown to commutative algebraists, in part because they do not preserve basic properties such as Noetherianity. This work wants to make a strong case against these prejudices. More precisely, it studies ultraproducts of Noetherian local rings from a purely algebraic perspective, as well as how they can be used to transfer results between the positive and zero characteristics, to derive uniform bounds, to define tight closure in characteristic zero, and to prove asymptotic versions of homological conjectures in mixed characteristic. Some of these results are obtained using variants called chromatic products, which are often even Noetherian. This book, neither assuming nor using any logical formalism, is intended for algebraists and geometers, in the hope of popularizing ultraproducts and their applications in algebra.*

Let me copy the chapter titles here:

Introduction
Ultraproducts and Łoś’ Theorem
Flatness
Uniform Bounds
Tight Closure in Positive Characteristic
Tight Closure in Characteristic Zero. Affine Case
Tight Closure in Characteristic Zero. Local Case
Cataproducts
Protoproducts
Asymptotic Homological Conjectures in Mixed Characteristic

Comment: Thank you, the book's title sounds definitely tailor-made :)